# how to make navigation drawer using navigation view with custom layout for the rows android

Tags: android

I am making navigation drawer with navigaiton view (content is taking from menu)

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

I want to change the default layout of the menu from drawer_view.xml.

Is android provide any means(actionLayout not working) for changing the default layout of menus

Comment: Can you explain your question in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Create drawer.xml inside menu folder and add this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="Home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/info"
            android:title="Info" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/other"
            android:title="Other" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/other1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/other1"
            android:title="Other 1" />

        <item android:title="Sub Menus">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub_one"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sub"
                    android:title="Sub item 1" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub_two"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sub"
                    android:title="Sub item 2" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub3"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sub"
                    android:title="Sub item 3" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub4"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sub"
                    android:title="Sub item 4" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

And replace

```
app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
```

inside NavigationView with this

```
app:menu="@menu/drawer"
```

So you can edit images and text for each menu option.

Comment: Yes thats what I am doing right now... but it has default layout which shows one image and one textView. I want to use my custom layout in place of every row of drawer.  Do you have any idea about this ?